# How to avoid bad input/output file name as well bad arguments in a C program

Tags: python, c, file, error-handling

I need to avoid bad input/output file name as well as invalid arguments. I have also used something like this but it's not really helping:

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {


             case 'i':
                      inFile = strdup(optarg);
             break;
             case 'o':
                      outFile = strdup(optarg);
             break;
             default:
                      //usage(argv[0]);
                      break;
    }
}

      if ((ptr1 = fopen(inFile, "r+")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open file %s\n", inFile);
            exit(-1);
    }
    if ((ptr = fopen(outFile, "w+")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open file %s\n", outFile);
            exit(-1);
    }
```

The python program which tests my program is as follows:

```
class Arg2(Test):
   name = "arg2"
   description = "bad arguments"
   timeout = 5
   def run(self):
      self.runexe(["fastsort", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
            stderr = usage_error, status = 1)
      self.done()

class Badin(Test):
   name = "badin"
   description = "bad input file"
   timeout = 5
   def run(self):
      invalid = mktemp(prefix='/invalid/path/')
      self.runexe(["fastsort", "-i", invalid, "-o", "outfile"],
          stderr = "Error: Cannot open file {0}\n".format(invalid), status = 1)
      self.done()

class Badout(Test):
   name = "badout"
   description = "bad output file"
   timeout = 5
   def run(self):
      infile = self.project_path + "/infile"
      # create a valid (empty) input file
      open(infile, "a").close()
      invalid = mktemp(prefix='/invalid/path/')
      self.runexe(["fastsort", "-i", infile, "-o", invalid],
          stderr = "Error: Cannot open file {0}\n".format(invalid), status = 1)
      self.done()
```

Can you please give me some hints and code snippet of usual methods of avoiding bad file name/bad file path as well as invalid argument handling in C?

Comment: In what way is it "not really helping"? What's wrong with the error messages and return values? What do you want different? (Although you might want to log the `errno` or `strerror`. And you might want to return a positive number like `1` instead of `-1`, because that might imply to some that you've exited because you caught a SIGHUP.)

Comment: Also, what is a "bad file name"? On most platforms, almost any character can appear in a filename—on POSIX, `/` will be interpreted as a path separator instead of part of the name, and `\000` as the end of the filename instead of part of it, but anything else goes, so there's nothing to check for. The one major exception is Windows; if you want Windows-specific error info you probably want to use `CreateFile` instead of `fopen` anyway, but you can always print out what `errno` is for `fopen("a\n?*:\003", "w+")` and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "bad file name" and "bad path name" you mean a path that you can't open because something is wrong with the filename or pathname, then the general way you're going about this is right: Try the `fopen`, and report the error after the fact, instead of trying to guess whether it would work.

What you're missing is checking the `errno` on failure. Instead of this generic error:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open file %s\n", inFile);
```

… print out something specific by using `errno`, `strerror`, or `perror`:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open file ");
perror(inFile);
```

Then you'll get something like:

```
Error: cannot open file foo/bar: No such file or directory.
```

If you want to distinguish between errors programmatically, just check `errno`:

```
if (errno == ENOENT) {
    /* The directory, or one of its parents, doesn't exist, so handle that */
} else {
    /* whatever */
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to pass the information back to the calling program, just return `errno` as your retcode:

```
exit(errno)
```

This is not a typical thing to do—but then `exit(-1)` isn't either. Normally you use `1` for "generic failure", and -1 for "I quit because I caught signal 1".

---

Meanwhile, it's not clear what you mean by "bad file name" and "bad path name", but it seems like all of these would count:

- The filename part of the path is too long. `errno` will be ENAMETOOLONG.
- The entire pathname is too long. `errno` will be ENAMETOOLONG.
- The specified directory, or one of the parents specified along the chain, doesn't exist. `errno` will be `ENOENT`.
- The specified directory, or one of the parents, isn't a directory. `errno` will be `ENOTDIR`.
- Invalid characters in the pathname. There is no such thing in POSIX, so this will only happen on non-POSIX platforms like Windows, which generally don't define what errors you get back from calling C and POSIX functions. (If you really want to deal with Windows errors, you probably want to use `CreateFile` rather than `fopen`, etc.)

If you need to deal with the last case on Windows or some other platform, the best thing to do is test it: try to `fopen("a b \\?*:; \n \003", "w+")` and see what you get. Then you'll know what to put in your code.

Comment: isn't using stat a better approach than opening the file? Like say, if the file is already open for writing, causing a COW...

Comment: @Dru: Presumably her real program is actually going to _do_ something with the file (otherwise, calling it `fastsort` is more than a little misleading…), and she's just trying to add better error handling to it. It's always better to just try to open and handle failure than to stat first and then assume you can open.

Comment: There _is_ such a thing as invalid characters in POSIX pathnames: **the null byte** (i.e., `\x00`). Attempts to embed null bytes in pathnames on POSIX platforms _will_ reliably result in `"TypeError: embedded NUL character"` exceptions on calls to `os` module functions.

Comment: @CecilCurry No, NUL characters are not invalid in POSIX pathnames. There's just no way to create or access such files from any POSIX API, because they all use NUL-terminated strings. But a POSIX-compliant system that also had non-POSIX APIs that used a different string standard could allow them.

Comment: @CecilCurry Of course CPython's `os` module just uses the POSIX and/or C stdlib functions on non-Windows plafform's, meaning it has to convert strings to NUL-terminated bytes, and there's no reasonable way to do that with a string that has an ASCII or Unicode NUL in the middle of it, so it raises a `TypeError`. But that error is from Python, not from the OS. (And you obviously won't get it in C, so you don't have to worry about how to handle it in the OP's C code.)